# How to remote word string in string javascript not use replace(), split()?

Tags: javascript

Write a function that enters a large string and a small string, which returns a string that deletes the small string from the larger string without the replace(),
var s1 = 'abc def abc ghr',
var s1 = 'abc'

Comment: So you want us to do your homework?

Answer (score -1):

```
function removeSmallString(smallStr, largeStr) {
    while (largeStr.indexOf(smallStr) !== -1) {
        var index = largeStr.indexOf(smallStr);
        largeStr = largeStr.substr(0, index) + largeStr.substr(index + smallStr.length)
    }
    return largeStr;
}
```

Comment: Thanh you  programming for fun